# neo4j + heroku in embedded mode; storage options?

Tags: java, heroku, neo4j, storage

I need to deploy neo4j in embedded mode to a cloud solution(such as heroku) and store the database somewhere else - i am thinking about multiple problems.

If i store in s3, i will have to retrieve the database, load it all in memory, and then send updates constantly with the new database. This is obviously not valid.

I am reluctant to using the neo4j add-on, because i can only use the REST calls, can only deploy in the US region, and i can't use server plugins.

Any ideas/solutions?

Best

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the founders of [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com). We don't support embedded mode, but we are about to release support for custom plugins and server extensions.

Our shared databases are hosted in the US and our dedicated servers can be setup in any AWS region.

Answer (score 1):

You should check http://www.graphenedb.com/ which is a hosted neo4j service.